# Compiling R 4.3.1 on Ubuntu22.04 failed with lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `u_versionToString_58'

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to install R into a specific folder so I build it from source on Ubuntu 22.04. After downloading R 4.3.1 I do the following:

```
sudo sed -i.bak "/^#.*deb-src.*universe$/s/^# //g" /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt build-dep r-base

./configure     --prefix=/data/shared/photon/opt/R/ubuntu22/${R_VERSION}     --enable-R-shlib     --enable-memory-profiling     --with-blas     --with-lapack
make -j 4
```

I get the following compiler issue:

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/R-4.3.1/src/main'
gcc -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L"../../lib" -L/usr/local/lib -o R.bin Rmain.o  -lR 
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `u_versionToString_58'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `u_getVersion_58'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `uloc_setDefault_58'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_setStrength_58'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_open_58'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_close_58'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_strcollIter_58'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_setAttribute_58'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `uiter_setUTF8_58'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ucol_getLocaleByType_58'
```

Ubuntu comes with libicu70 and the libR is provided by the R source. How can I fix this? Is there an R binary for ubuntu22 which I can download and install in a specific location without apt install?

Comment: This makes no sense to me, and I have looked after the Debian (and Ubuntu) package for 20 years.  For starters, you don't need you `sed` line for a compilation.  Second, if the linking fails then then earlier `configure` step cannot have worked.  Third, if you watn to rebuild a package you need to change options in its `debian/rules` (and I apologize for how sprawling it is, but hey, it still works).  Maybe come to the r-sig-debian list for a longer exchange than we can have here in a comment box.

Comment: I misread one part earlier; your `apt build-dep` step is correct to get the correct build-dependencies.  You don't show much in terms of what OS or Ubuntu version, if any, you are on but the above should work.  If `libicu58` creeps in you may have an older build in the same directory -- we cannot tell and have to guess.

Comment: The other thing you should be aware is that standard Debian and Ubuntu packages are compiled in a 'cleanroom' -- usually a `chroot`.  If libicu58 is on your system as a development package, the compiler will use that.  So you may want to consider building in a Ubuntu 22.04 Docker container, or for example use launchpad.net which I find helpful for local / personal packages.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I didn't manage to compile it and gave up. I went on and used a docker container as you suggested

Comment: Glad you are up and working now via Docker.. You must have something misaligned on your system as these builds (R, from source, Ubunut) a very standard and common and done a thousands of people.  And there are of course pre-made binaries used by even more people without a hitch.